# style a <thead>

Tags: html, css

I have the following :

```
<table style="border:solid 1px; border-color:black">
  <thead style="border:solid 2px; border-color:black"> 
    <tr>
      <th>
        <p>Document Date</p>
      </th>
      <th>
        <p>Buy-from Vendor No.</p>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p>18/03/11</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>C01753</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p>18/03/11</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>C00522</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I'd like to add a border around the whole table and one around the whole header. The table border is showing nicely (Internet Explorer), but the header border is not.

PS: I use inline styles because it's meant for a HTML body in a mail message.

**EDIT**

The following gave me what I wanted in Firefox, not in IE though

```
<table style="border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse;">
  <thead>
    <tr style="border: 1px solid black">
    ...
```

**EDIT**

Added coloring

```
<table style="border: 2px solid black; border-collapse: collapse;">
  <thead>
    <tr style="border: 1px solid black; background-color: #EEE;">
    ...
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1396317/how-do-i-create-borders-around-tbody-thead-sections-of-a-table, but I have to admit being reticent to mark it as such, since the other question isn't really answered.

Comment: @TJ Crowder: Yeah, found that one too, but using javascript isn't really the answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `rules="groups"` and change your structure a bit:

```
<table style="border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse;" rules="groups">
  <thead style="border: 2px solid black;"> 
    <tr>
      <th>
        <p>Document Date</p>
      </th>
      <th>
        <p>Buy-from Vendor No.</p>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p>18/03/11</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>C01753</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p>18/03/11</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>C00522</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

---

**EDIT**: Well, that doesn's seem to work in IE. In that case, I'd suggest:

```
<table style="border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse;">
  <thead>
    <tr style="background-color: black; color: white;">
      <!-- ... -->
```

Comment: +1, seems to work: http://jsbin.com/urubi5 Renders quite differently in IE7 compared with Chrome or IE9, but still... Re your edit: It worked for me in both IE7 and IE9. In IE7 the underline under the `thead` is very faint, but it's there.

Comment: @T.J., yeah, quite differently :D  Still, personally, I'd rather use the later solution with background-color.

Comment: Sorry, this worked... in Firefox. MSIE gives me the finger. :( That is, no border around the header. Still, a standards-compliant answer is good enough. Combined with balexandre's coloring I got something I can use.

Answer (score 6):

You can't style a `<thead>` element, you need to style the `<tr>`

for example, like [this](http://jsbin.com/epavo4/2/edit)

```
<table style="border:solid 1px black" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <thead> 
    <tr style="background-color: #EEE;">
      <th>
        <p>Document Date</p>
      </th>
      <th>
        <p>Buy-from Vendor No.</p>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
...
```

border styling does not apply, the normal thing is use the background color.

and **btw** `border` supports 3 attributes, including the color as well like

```
border: solid 1px black;
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip about using background, it does look nicer

Answer (score 2):

You can't style thead directly, but, you can style the child elements.

For example

```
<table>
  <thead> 
    <tr>
      <th>
        <p>Document Date</p>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <p>18/03/11</p>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

If you want to style just the th of the thead, then your css is

```
thead th { mystyles }
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5965Y/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that that `thead` renders and is more for organisation. Style the row instead. UPDATE: tr does not support border either. Update version below.

## EDIT

```
<table style="border:solid 1px; border-color:black;border-collapse:collapse;">
<thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="border:solid 2px black;border-right:none">
        <p>Document Date</p>
      </th>
      <th style="border:solid 2px black;border-left:none">
        <p>Buy-from Vendor No.</p>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p>18/03/11</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>C01753</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p>18/03/11</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>C00522</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The border can be specified on a table or a cell (td or th). Specify a top and bottom border on all cells, a left border on the first cell and a right border on the last cell. To prevent gaps between the borders of cells the border-collapse style of the table needs to be set to `border-collapse:collapse`.

Comment: Styling the <tr> does nothing

Comment: I was sure that I have used that before, code updated (and tested).

Comment: I really would not like styling each individual cell. I have like, 20 columns in reality.

Comment: It is simpler if using CSS as opposed to inline styles. Given that this requires inline styles using the background as suggested in other answers is a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the style on your `<tr>` rather than `<thead>`.

Also, you can shorten the css like this: style="border: 2px solid black"

Comment: Styling the <tr> does nothing